# Why do I get this error when I try to load the component in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have to try to attempt but the solution is still the same, do I have miss any steps?

```
<template>
<div>
      <component v-bind:is="components"></component>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import invbo from './components/inventory.vue';
import itemsrbo from './components/itemsearch.vue';
import mainbo from './components/mainbo.vue';
export default {
  components:{
    'inventory':invbo,
    'item-search':itemsrbo,
    'mainbo':mainbo,

  },
  data(){
    return{
      components: 'mainbo'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Error message

```
./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.auto-import.js?kebab!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/inventory.vue' in 'C:\Users\...\src\views'
```

And here the sample code on what I am trying to do to load the vue components from the components directory.

Comment: In your samle code, you aren't having any import of `blabla.vue`, is the error actually corresponding to the code you pasted?

Comment: sorry sir, I already edit the question

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your current project structure ?

Comment: do you  actually have `./components/inventory.vue`  in your project?

Comment: yes i already create in component directory but still cant load the component

Comment: Paths are relative. If this file is in the **components** directory as well, then you don’t need to include it in the path (`import invbo from './inventory.vue';`).

Comment: https://snipboard.io/Vlq6mK.jpg

Comment: @MartinBean i got same error too

Comment: Well what does your directory structure look like? Where is file in your directory?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/Vlq6mK.jpg @MartinBean here the structure

Comment: And which file does the code you’ve shared in your question belong to?

Comment: Home.vue sir which is i have put the code that I mention

Comment: So you need to use the correct relative path, then: `import invbo from '../components/inventory.vue`

Comment: Damn, thank you sir that small dots solve the problem. thanks soo much sir for the support

Comment: [PROBLEM SOLVED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to use the correct relative path, then: `import invbo from '../components/inventory.vue` answer by @MartinBean

Answer (score 1):

Post the inventory component?

At inventory.vue

You should export the component as:

```
export default {}
```